# accessing array of strings in C

Tags: c, string, initialization

How to declare array of strings in C.
Is it like

```
char str[100][100] ={"this","that","those"};
```

If so how to access the values .. can i travers like this?
(It does not give any compilation error ..but shows some additional garbage characters)

```
int i ,j;
char  c[100][100] = {"this","that"};
for(i = 0 ;c[i] != '\0';++i)
 for(j = 0; c[i][j] != '\0';++j)
   printf("%c",c[i][j]);
```

Is it necessary to add '\0' at end of eac string..for ex:

```
 char c[100][100]={"this\0","that\0"}
```

Comment: printf("%s",c[i]) would print the string at index `i`.

Comment: That's a nice idea....thanks....will %s prints whitespace?

Comment: yes,prints until the eof string is reached i.e '\0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to declare array of strings in C

It is Ok, but you will have to be extremely careful of [buffer-overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) when dealing with these strings

> can i travers like this?

Note that the condition in the first for loop: `for(i = 0 ;c[i] != '\0';++i)` is probably wrong, and will fail since `c[i]` is an array, whose address is not 0. You should probably iterate the outer array by numbers [until you read all elements], and not until you find some specific character. You can do that by maintaining a different variable `n`, which will indicate how many elements does the array currently have.

> Is it necessary to add '\0' at end of eac string..for ex:

No - the compiler add it to you, it is just fine without adding the `'\0'` to the string.

Comment: so i<100 is condition there?=>If i have only two elements and the rest space is filled later,this condition will do more useless iterations ?
How to avoid that?

Comment: It will fail if C has fewer than 100 strings, too.

Comment: i have changed the comment...added that comment just before you edited your comment...anyway what is the answer for my question in that comment?

Comment: @JinuJD: You could maintain a different variable `n`, which will indicate how many strings are currently in the array, and iterate while `i < n`. Otherwise you might fail if there are no empty strings, or if an empty string, which is usually a feasible value will appear in the middle of the array.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can declare an array of strings that way.
2. No, you can't traverse it like that, the condition on your outer loop is bad - a string (`char *`) will never be equal to a character `'\0'`. The inner loop is fine.
3. No, you don't need to add the `'\0'`, that will happen automatically.

Comment: so what should be the condition in outer loop?

Comment: @Jinu, you can check cloudy goose's answer for a working example.  Just watch out for the case where your array is full, since that answer won't work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

c[i] is a pointer, so it has nothing to do with '\0'
so instead you should check c[i][0]
The compiler will add '\0' for you when you input a string like "this"

```
char str[100][100] ={"this","that","those"};
int main()
{
    int i ,j;
    char  c[100][100] = {"this","that"};
    for(i = 0 ;c[i][0] != '\0';++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; c[i][j] != '\0';++j)
            printf("%c",c[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: so is this condition sufficient in outer loop c[i]!=NULL (or just c[i])?

Comment: @JinuJDNo, `c[i]` is an address, and is never `NULL`. Also, if `c[i][0]`: is enough depends on the data. If you are guaranteed to have less then 100 strings, and you are guaranteed that the empty string is not a feasible value in the array, and you are guaranteed the 100th entree in the array is marked with being the [only] empty string, it will work.